# Show/hide stack panel child elements

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a stackpanel a TextBlock. When i tap on it,I want to display a couple of text boxes right below TextBlock and within the stack panel. And when I tap on TextBlock again the textboxes should not be visible. How can I accompalish this by just using XAML?

Comment: WPF or Windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

By just using XAML and nothing else, you can't. You have to have either a code behind or a view model bound to the page.

Add all textboxes to the `StackPanel` and set their `Visibility` to `Collapsed`. Also give each one a name using the `x:Name` property. As for your `TextBlock`, set `IsHitTestVisible` to true and add Tap handler. In the tap handler change the visibility of the previously added and named `TextBox`es.

In case you want to use MVVM, bind visibility to some bool value and add converter from bool to visibility. Also add an event to command trigger to the text block element and handle it in your view model - there you will toggle the same bool property that all those text boxes are bound to.